# Use rtcwake without entering a password

Tags: sudo, shutdown

I would like to execute something like `rtcwake -m off -s 60` without entering a password.

I used visudo to write the following line into /etc/sudoers:
`%sudo ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown, /sbin/poweroff, /sbin/halt, /sbin/reboot`

Now I can shutdown without entering a password. However, using rtcwake without password does not work. Instead, I get the following message:

`rtcwake: assuming RTC uses UTC ...
rtcwake: wakeup from "off" using /dev/rtc0 at Fri Dec 18 17:45:43 2015
shutdown: Need to be root`

What is missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it. I added the following line to /etc/rc.local:

> sudo chmod ugo+r rtc0

and with
`%sudo ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown, /sbin/poweroff, /usr/sbin/rtcwake`
in /etc/sudoers. Note that I do not care about security because my application is running on a dedicated computer which does not run critical tasks.

edit: included `/usr/sbin/rtcwake` in /etc/sudoers according to Gilles answer.

Comment: Apart from embedded systems without udev, `chmod … /dev/rtc0` won't survive a reboot. `chmod +s /sbin/shutdown` allows anyone to run `shutdown`, so it's a security hole unless you're the sole user of the machine and it doesn't run any software that risks having a security hole.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already trusting the user to shut down the system at any time, let them call `rtcwake` as root. Run `visudo` and add `/usr/sbin/rtcwake` to the line with `/sbin/shutdown` and so on.

Comment: Without `sudo chmod ugo+r rtc0` I still get the error message: **rtcwake: open failed: /dev/rtc0: Permission denied**.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new udev rule to achieve that.

Create a new `40-rtc-permissions.rules` file in `/lib/udev/rules.d` or `/etc/udev/rules.d` (depending on your distro)
where you can put the following line

```
KERNEL=="rtc0", GROUP="wheel"
```

Group doesn't have to be wheel. It can be whichever user group you want to have access to the rtc0 device.